# Why is PHP POSTing to the redirected url?

Tags: php, redirect

I am writing a PHP REST API and trying to redirect a POST request to the GET of the new resource, but when I change the location with `header()` it stays on the post request. In this isolated example, it goes into a redirect loop both on my live deployment and locally on my PHP built-in web server.

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    http_response_code(303);
    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", true, 303);
    exit();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    echo "Hello World!";
}
```

When I make a request from Postman, I get the following:

> Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop

I expect "Hello World!" to be echoed to the browser, and I only get this expected output when I run the built-in web server directly on my file: `php -S localhost:8000 api/test.php`

Shouldn't the request method change to GET when I add and replace a location header?

Comment: You should use "option", during POST method return: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS" or you can change config of your server.

Comment: Presumably then, the location you are redirecting to is then redirecting again, and so on, infinitely

Comment: `the request method change to GET when I add and replace a location header?`...it should yes. I'm not sure off the top of my head what postman offers for tracing redirects but if you were to trigger this in a browser the network tool ought to show you the first few requests so you can hopefully see more clearly what's happening

Comment: The code you posted should work fine. It's likely that the code you're having a problem with is not the same as what you posted here.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue Would it help if I posted my router file for local development or my Vercel configuration file? Those are the only other files I can think of that are involved in this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Postman client I was using. I needed to switch off **Follow original HTTP Method** in order for the request to do the default behavior of switching from POST to GET. And indeed, it works in the browser from the Network tab of the Developer tools.